# Como Fazer a Passagem de Parâmetros no JasperReports

Tags: java, postgresql, servlet, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Olá Pessoal boa tarde estou com uma duvida que está me matando. Tenho um projeto que tem que imprimir um relatório que contem duas listas e duas tabelas. Meu problema é o seguinte, estou sem intender como o jasper interpreta os dados que são passados pra ele, por causa do seguinte:

No meu relatório na primeira vez que eu fiz, no jasper studio eu criei o relatório com um banco fixo lá funcionava tudo perfeitamente, e ai eu passei esse relatório para o java, lá quando eu rodava o código o relatório era gerado com o banco que foi criado no jasper studio e não com os dados passado pelo java.

Então eu mudei o relatório e ai surgiram mais duvidas, por que eu mudei para a utilização de parâmetros e criei as listas e tabelas sem banco de dados, mas o relatório nem aparece, mesmo eu passando os parâmetros pelo java. A minha duvida é como o jasper interpreta esses dados que eu estou passando, tipo, no meu código eu passo a conexão do banco que eu estou usando, é mesmo necessário passa-la já que eu passo as informações por parâmetro?

Outra duvida, pesquisando na internet reparei que posso colocar parâmetros nas sqls dos dataset que crio no jasper studio, como que eu consigo passar esse parâmetros via java?

Abaixo segue os códigos que fiz até agora:

Classe que Gera o Relatório:

```
private Connection conexao;

public GeradorRelatorio(Connection conexao) {
    this.conexao = conexao;
}

public void geraPdf(String jrxml, 
    Map<String, Object> parametros, OutputStream saida) {

    try {
        // compila jrxml em memoria
        JasperReport jasper = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jrxml);

        // preenche relatorio
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasper, parametros, this.conexao);

        // exporta para pdf
        JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print);
        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, saida);

        exporter.exportReport();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Classe que faz a passagem de Parâmetros:

```
@WebServlet("/RelatorioMensalController")
public class RelatorioMensalController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Conexao conexao;
private ParametrosRelatorio pr = new ParametrosRelatorio();

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    int idUsuario = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idUsuario"));
    System.out.println(idUsuario);
    // acha jrxml dentro da aplicação
    ServletContext contexto = request.getServletContext();
    String jrxml = contexto.getRealPath("relatorio/exemplo.jrxml");

    // prepara parâmetros
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();

    List<Conta> listaConta = pr.buscarContaUsuario(idUsuario);
    for (Conta conta : listaConta) {
        parametros.put("nomeConta", conta.getNome());
        parametros.put("saldo", conta.getSaldo());
        List<Debito> listaDebito = pr.buscarDebitosContasMesAtual(idUsuario, conta.getId());
        for (Debito debito : listaDebito) {
            parametros.put("descricaoDebitoConta", debito.getDescricao());
            parametros.put("valorDebitoConta", debito.getValor());
            parametros.put("dataDebitoConta", debito.getData());
        }
    }

    List<CartaoDeCredito> listaCartao = pr.buscarCartaoUsuario(idUsuario);
    for (CartaoDeCredito cartaoDeCredito : listaCartao) {
        parametros.put("nomeCartao", cartaoDeCredito.getNome());
        parametros.put("limite", cartaoDeCredito.getLimite());
        parametros.put("valorTotal", cartaoDeCredito.getValorTotal());
        parametros.put("vencimento", cartaoDeCredito.getVencimento());
        List<Debito> listaDebitoCartao = pr.buscarDebitosCartaoMesAtual(idUsuario, cartaoDeCredito.getId());
        for (Debito debito : listaDebitoCartao) {
            parametros.put("descricaoDebitoCartao", debito.getDescricao());
            parametros.put("valorDebitoCartao", debito.getValor());
            parametros.put("dataDebitoCartao", debito.getData());
        }
    }

    List<Object> listaCategoriaCartao = pr.buscarCategoriaCartaoMesAtual(idUsuario);
    for (Object object : listaCategoriaCartao) {
        if (object.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
            parametros.put("nomeCategoriaCartao", object);
            System.out.println(object);
        } else {
            parametros.put("quantidadeCartao", object);
        }
    }

    List<Object> listaCategoriaConta = pr.buscarCategoriaContaMesAtual(idUsuario);
    for (Object object : listaCategoriaConta) {
        if (object.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
            parametros.put("nomeCategoriaConta", object);
        } else {
            parametros.put("quantidadeConta", object);
        }
    }

    // abre conexão com o banco
    conexao = Conexao.getConexao();

    // gera relatório
    GeradorRelatorio gerador = new GeradorRelatorio(conexao.getConnection());
    gerador.geraPdf(jrxml, parametros, response.getOutputStream());

}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}
```

Espero que vocês consigam me ajudar, nunca tinha trabalhado antes com jasper reports então eu estou bem confusa, não sei como ele funciona.

Obrigada desde já  todos.

Comment: Caso necessitem de mais informações é só pedir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro sobre a conexao com o banco de dados.

Porque voce tem que passar uma conexao nesse seu caso, quando voce esta criando um relátorio geralmente cria de acordo com as informacoes do banco de dados que quer mostrar, assim quando esta criando um relatorio em ferramentas como JasperStudio você cria uma conexao para fazer os testes com os dados reais.

Depois quando vai gerar o relatório voce necessita enviar a conexao para o Jasper saber de onde vai pegar esses dados.

Na verdade o Jasper funciona da seguinte maneira, geralmente se cria um relatorio em um software como JasperStudio. 
Dentro dele voce tem várias opcoes para montar seu relatório como adicionar textos fixos ou imagens e assim por diante conforme desejar e dentro dele há também uma opçao parametro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você cria um parametro que pode ser utilizado como voce mesmo disse em `Querys SQL` e para setar esses valores de parametros é passado o HashMap com os parametros como voce já está fazendo.

Por exemplo, digamos que criou um parametro que se chama "ID", para atribuir o valor a ele na sua hashMap voce seta o valor da seguinte maneira.

Quando seu relatório for gerado ele vai utilizado esse valor passado no seu relatorio.

`parametros.put("ID","VALOR")`

Se possuí alguma dúvida aqui há bom exemplo: [exemplo de relatório](http://www.mauda.com.br/?p=1420)

Answer (score 0):

Obrigada pela explicação, vim pesquisando desde que coloquei a questão aqui e junto com a sua explicação entendi oq estava fazendo errado. Mas ainda assim não resolvi o meu problema. Vou tentar explicar melhor. Eu tenho um sistema de gerenciamento financeiro pessoal, e quero disponibilizar um relatório que contenha as contas e os cartões do usuário assim como os débitos relacionados a eles, além de dois gráficos com as categorias em que o usuário mais gastou.

A estrategia que usei para criar o relatório foi de colocar o elemento list para listar as contas e cartões e dentro dele coloquei um table com os débitos. Nos datasets dos elementos coloquei querys com parâmetro só que eu não consigo passar os dados para esses parâmetros. Não sei se estou usando a estrategia correta ou não, porque nunca tinha utilizado o jasper antes, então eu to bem confusa em como por essas informações no relatório.

Se você tiver alguma sugestão de como organizar ou montar melhor o relatório eu agradeceria muito.

Comment: Repositório do Código do Relatório: https://github.com/JessPergentino/relatorio.git